# Comparar objetos no R

Tags: r, comparação

Tenho dois dataframes:

```
atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa
1995-01-01        74.35501        35.59109
1995-02-01        74.06131        35.43400
1995-03-01        74.06131        35.93259
```

e:

```
atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa PIMPF_Br_A_3_sa
1995-01-01        74.35501        35.59109        79.39399
1995-02-01        74.06131        35.43400        79.29079
1995-03-01        74.06131        35.93259        79.22728
```

Estou usando a função `identical` para verificar se os dois são iguais e gostaria que se retornasse `FALSE`, retornasse a coluna que é diferente entre os dois dataframes.

O codigo que estou usando:

```
comparar <- identical(df1, df2)
if (comparar == TRUE){
    print("Os dados são iguais")
} else {
    print("Os dados não são iguais")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta função compara coluna a coluna com `identical` e tem como saída um vetor lógico com os nomes das colunas do primeiro dataframe. Se um nome de coluna existir no primeiro df mas não no segundo, o valor é `NA`.

```
comparar <- function(DF1, DF2){
  inx <- match(names(DF1), names(DF2))
  res <- sapply(inx, function(i) {
    if(is.na(i))
      NA
    else
      identical(DF1[i], DF2[i])
  })
  names(res) <- names(DF1)
  res
}

comparar(df1, df2)
#     atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa 
#           TRUE            TRUE            TRUE 
comparar(df2, df1)
#     atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa PIMPF_Br_A_3_sa 
#           TRUE            TRUE            TRUE              NA
```

**Dados.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa
1995-01-01        74.35501        35.59109
1995-02-01        74.06131        35.43400
1995-03-01        74.06131        35.93259
", header = TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text = "
atualizada PIMPF_Br_A_1_sa PIMPF_Br_A_2_sa PIMPF_Br_A_3_sa
1995-01-01        74.35501        35.59109        79.39399
1995-02-01        74.06131        35.43400        79.29079
1995-03-01        74.06131        35.93259        79.22728
", header = TRUE)
```